# Incompatible layer with Tensorflow and LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm trying to create a network to predict a time series with arbitrary size (i.e. time_steps = None). I'm testing different topologies, but I wanted a 7 neuron input layer (time series in the input has 7 dimensions), and a one neuron output layer (value to forecast is one-dimensional), between them, I'm testing with several a variable number of LSTM layers, each with a variable number of neurons. I want to use CuDNN (just to be faster), so there are some restrictions to the parameters I use. Sometimes I get this strange error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 5)
```

The minimal code to reproduce the problem is given below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

rnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, 7)))
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(5, activation="tanh", return_sequences=False, unroll=False,
                             recurrent_activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, time_major=True,
                             recurrent_dropout=0, stateful=False, input_shape=(None, 7)))
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(5, activation="tanh", return_sequences=False, unroll=False,
                             recurrent_activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, time_major=True,
                             recurrent_dropout=0, stateful=False, input_shape=(None, 5)))
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))
```

Why does this problem happen? The exact same message is shown if I change the `input_shape` parameter to `(1, None, 5)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you stack LSTM layers then you must set the layer's parameter return_sequence=True. Only the last layer of the LSTM layer must return return_sequence=False.

```
import tensorflow as tf

rnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, 7)))
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(5, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True, unroll=False, # Changed Line
                             recurrent_activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, time_major=True,
                             recurrent_dropout=0, stateful=False, input_shape=(None, 7))),
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(5, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True, unroll=False, # Changed Line
                             recurrent_activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, time_major=True,
                             recurrent_dropout=0, stateful=False, input_shape=(None, 7)))
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(5, activation="tanh", return_sequences=False, unroll=False, # must keep return_sequences=False as the next layer is the Dense layer
                             recurrent_activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, time_major=True,
                             recurrent_dropout=0, stateful=False, input_shape=(None, 5)))
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `return_sequences` to be equal `True` in the first LSTM layer.

I may be wrong, but I believe that `input_shape`, while being 3D, is already aware of the `batch_size` based on the data. This means that what the other comment suggested is actually going to output 4D data.

Here's an example that runs:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
rnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, 7)))
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(5, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True, unroll=False,
                             recurrent_activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, time_major=True,
                             recurrent_dropout=0, stateful=False, input_shape=(None, 7)))
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(5, activation="tanh", return_sequences=False, unroll=False,
                             recurrent_activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, time_major=True,
                             recurrent_dropout=0, stateful=False, input_shape=(None, 5)))
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))

# random data with the the (1, 7) shape
train = np.random.rand(10, 1, 7)
labels = np.random.randint(0, 1, 10)


rnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

rnn.fit(train, labels)
```